# Fixed length numeric value - BIGINT or CHAR data type?

Tags: mysql

I have a couple numeric fields which will be storing fixed length numeric values, I don't need to do any math on these fields or sorting by highest to lowest or anything like that, so I'm wondering if using the `CHAR` data type would be better than using a `BIGINT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fixed-width number and it fits in a `decimal` field, then use that data type.  Something like `decimal(15, 0)` should give you want you want.

If the choice is between a fixed width character and a string, I would probably go with a string in this case.  I find that `char(15)` makes more sense than storing a 15-digit number in a `bigint` field.  This makes it clear that the field is really an identifier of some sort, rather than an actual number.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is numeric, use a numeric field. You never know when your requirements will change and you'll need to do numeric processing on the field.